# Layout Alignment Issues For Device to Device

Tags: android

1. When I try to run my project on LG Android Mobile then there is no alignment issues come with this device it is a 3.2 HVGA but when I try to run it on Motorola it is a 3.7 WVGA then it gives complete layout alignment issues so can you tell me suggestion to implement layouts uniquely to every device.
2. I don't know is it possible or not to make a unique layout design for all devices.

Comment: Can you post some examples of your layouts? Android contains mechanisms which will get your layouts to work across various form factors, but you need to structure your layouts correctly to allow it to do that well. Without seeing your layouts it's difficult to suggest what may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom layouts by reading the device layout screen like this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

There are two ways you can create your layout. You can create your own algorithm that checks the difference between the resolution you have made your layout for, and gets the difference for the current screen size, and adjust all those values progmatically (long and tedious, but DEFINETELY will work on all devices)

Or, you can define a layout for each of the common devices in your layout folder. This requires alot more space and time though.

Comment: Oh, and Im guessing your using pixels as your unit of measurement, its best not to do that when possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create custom layouts for different devices, but you can for different screen densities and *sizes*, [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has all of the information you should need.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes back I was having this type of problem. Because I was using Pixels as my unit to specify height, width or any layout specific dimensions. But I changed those **px** to **dp** and it worked for me. I got same layout for all the screens. Hope if this may help you anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick checklist about how you can ensure that your application displays properly on different screens:

1.Use wrap_content, fill_parent, or dp units when specifying dimensions in an XML layout file 
2.Do not use hard coded pixel values in your application code 
3.Do not use AbsoluteLayout (it's deprecated) 
4.Supply alternative bitmap drawables for different screen densities